# How to display page numbers in PDF using groovy render plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using the Grails render plugin to render a GSP file as PDF. I need to display page numbers at the bottom of each page. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some research I figured out, that it's not really possible (since you can't really structure the GSP file into pages).

I decided to use Jasper for creating the reports.